# Не удается добавить объект своего класса в QList (Qt C++)

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь добавлять объекты собственного класса в QList,получаю ошибку.
Qlist в файле заголовка

'''

```
#include <QList>

extern QList<Plugs> PlugsList;
extern QList<OutLet> OutLetList;
```

'''
Класс

'''

```
#include "plugs.h"
#include "globalinformation.h"

Plugs::Plugs() : QGraphicsPixmapItem()
{
}
Plugs::Plugs(QGraphicsScene *MyScene,QString picurl,int x,int y, int PlugUID): QGraphicsPixmapItem()
{
    QPixmap  pic (picurl);
    this->setPixmap(pic);
    this->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    this->setPos(x, y);
    PlugsList.append(*this); //вот это вызывает ошибку при компиляции и не одну
    MyScene->addItem(this);

    Q_UNUSED(PlugUID);
}
```

'''

Тексты ошибок

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:465: ошибка: use of deleted function ‘Plugs::Plugs(const Plugs&)’
  465 |                 current->v = new T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src->v));
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:478: ошибка: use of deleted function ‘Plugs::Plugs(const Plugs&)’
  478 |                 new (current) T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src));
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/home/anton/QTProjects/Work02/plugs.h:8: ошибка: use of deleted function ‘QGraphicsPixmapItem& QGraphicsPixmapItem::operator=(const QGraphicsPixmapItem&)’
```

При этом никакой ошибки до компиляции нет, С++ издевается надо мной, что ему надо ?

Comment: Издеваетесь вы! Вам в описании ошибки явно сказано что не так... Читайте их.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916251/qlist-of-custom-objects

Answer (score 4):

Вы пытаетесь добавить *копию* Вашего объекта в список. Но Ваш объект отнаследованный от QGraphicsPixmapItem копировать не имеет смысла и разработчики Qt позаботились указать это компилятору, вот он и сообщает об ошибке.

Фундаментально Вам надо понять что C++ оператор присваивания и ряд аналогичных конструкций создает копии объектов а не перемещает их. Если у Вас есть переменная с именем (a) то эта переменная на самом деле является участком памяти которому дали символьное имя. Если Вы пишете конструкцию вида `a = b` то у Вас есть *два* кусочка памяти - один с именем (a), другой с именем (b). Если бы объект перемещался из области памяти с именем (b) в область памяти с именем (a) то после завершения этой операции имя (b) указывало бы на непонятно что, некоторую область памяти где ранее лежал объект а теперь ничего нет. Это было бы неудобно и сбивало бы с толку (такое можно реализовать вручную переопределением операторов и практическая попытка сделать это под названием std::auto_ptr осталась в памяти тех кто его пытался использовать тихим ужасом). Поэтому когда Вы говорите компилятору `a = b` то он копирует данные из области памяти с именем (b) в область памяти с именем (a). Аналогичным образом запись list.append(a) не перемещает область памяти (a) в область памяти отведенную под список, а создает в этой области памяти копию объекта (a).

В C++11 и более поздних в язык добавили возможность перемещать объекты, явно указывая что требуется именно перемещение (примерно так: `a = std::move(b)`) и Вы берете на себя понимание что имя (b) после этого перемещения использовать будет нельзя. Но QList в Qt не поддерживает move-семантику.

Вам скорее всего нужно просто заменить `QList<Plugs>` на `QList<Plugs*>`. Тогда Вы будете копировать не сам объект а указатель на него (содержимое области в памяти где лежит адрес другой области памяти где лежит сам объект).

Comment: Заменить QList на QList?

Comment: Черт, угловые скобочки съелись а я не заметил. Спасибо!